# This binary takes much more space than its dynamic counterpart located in e2fsprogs, though

Tags: software-installation

This is from Synaptic.

```
statically-linked version of the ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem checker
  
This may be of some help to you if your filesystem gets corrupted enough
to break the shared libraries used by the dynamically linked checker.

This binary takes much more space than its dynamic counterpart located
in e2fsprogs, though.

You may want to install a statically-linked shell as well, to be able
to run this program if something like your C library gets corrupted.
```

What does this mean?

```
This binary takes much more space than its **dynamic counterpart** located
    in e2fsprogs, though.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that this software is built static, so all its components are included into single deb-package. There are no dependencies for such package. This is because of the fact that binary is [linked as static](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_build) - it includes all possibly libraries in one file.

You can check package dependencies on https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/e2fsck-static to confirm that it does not have any must-installed dependencies.